# Why .net 4.6.1 needed when in target framework is 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild

I have one friend with Windows 7 OS (x64). For this OS .net 4.6.1 is unsupported.
I have on my pc Windows 10 (x64) with install vs community 2015 and here all working fine.

So, when my friend is trying to launch my app he gets request to install .net 4.6.1.

In vs project "Target framework" field is ".NET Framework 4.5.2"

Crutches from Microsoft?

and what can i do for fix that?

Comment: Are you sure about 4.6.1 being unsupported on Win7?  With SP1 it should be ok, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49981

Comment: But, why i getting builded app for .net 4.6.1 when needed 4.5.2?

Comment: Do you have an app config? What is listed in the startup/supportedruntimes element?

Comment: `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2015/06/17/a-couple-of-notes-about-net-framework-4-6-setup-behaviors/):

> The .NET Framework 4.6 is an in-place upgrade for all of the following versions of the .NET Framework:
>
> - .NET Framework 4
> - .NET Framework 4.5
> - .NET Framework 4.5.1
> - .NET Framework 4.5.2
>
> An in-place upgrade means that if you install the .NET Framework 4.6 when any of the above versions of versions of the .NET Framework are installed on your PC, .NET Framework 4.6 setup will upgrade them and you will be left with only the .NET Framework 4.6 installed afterwards.  In addition, any attempts to install older versions of the .NET Framework 4 family when the .NET Framework 4.6 is already present will result in .NET Framework setup blocking you from installing because it detects that a newer version is already installed.
>
> The .NET Framework 4.6 is designed to be compatible with all applications created with any version of the .NET Framework from 4 to 4.6, but there are sometimes application compatibility issues that arise, such as an installer that tells the user that they must install the .NET Framework 4.5 even if the .NET Framework 4.6 is already installed.  In cases like this, you might need to revert back from the .NET Framework 4.6 to an earlier version of the .NET Framework 4 family.  To do that, you must uninstall the .NET Framework 4.6 and then re-install the earlier version of the .NET Framework from the .NET Framework 4 family.

Basically, it is prompting you to install 4.6.1 because it is the highest version that is compatible with your program that is targeting 4.5.2, and the target machine apparently doesn't have any compatible framework (4.5.2 or higher) installed.